# can't type into textfield after requesting focus

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

when I input something from the textfield it should clear the text in the textfield and request focus and continue typing, the first two works but I can't type in the textfield once I request focus.
help?

```
FocusNode node = FocusNode();
TextField(
    focusNode: node,
    controller: controller,
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    onSubmitted: (value) {
        setState(() {
            if(value == (n1 * n2).toString()){
                score += 10;
                n1 = Random().nextInt(13) + 0;
                n2 = Random().nextInt(13) + 0;
                print(true);
            }
            else {
                lives -= 1;
                print(false);
            }

         });
         controller.clear();
         sleep(Duration(milliseconds: 10));
         node.requestFocus();
     },
     autofocus: true,
     decoration: InputDecoration(
         border: InputBorder.none
     ),
     style: TextStyle(
     color: Colors.white,
     fontSize: 48
     ),
),
```

Comment: is your `FocusNode node = FocusNode();` inside the build method?
plus, your `sleep(Duration(millisecond: 10));` will have no effect here

Answer (score 1):

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 10), () {
  node.requestFocus();
});
```

Try this.

Comment: This is working for me, but you know why it is required?

Answer (score 0):

Insure that your node initialization is not inside the build,
also, your `sleep` method is not working like that,
you should either do the following

```
void sleep(final Duration duration, {final VoidCallback? onDone}) {
    Future.delayed(duration, onDone);
}
//and use it like this,
sleep(Duration(milliseconds: 10), onDone: node.requestFocus);
```

OR

```
Future sleep(final Duration duration) async {
    await Future.delayed(duration);
}
//and use it like this
await sleep(Duration(milliseconds: 10));
node.requestFocus();
```

OR the known way, same as @aoiTenshi mentioned